# Attempting to tamper proof my executable with some hashing but coming across some unexpected and unknown compiler behaviour

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, compilation

In an attempt to tamper proof my executable with some hashing I've come across some unexpected and unknown compiler behaviour.

I have this idea of calculating a simple hash value of my program by simply adding all the bytes in the binary and using the remainder of that total divided by 256 as a hash value.

I figured that if in my program I have a string literal of "0000" and that the hash I calculate with the above algorithm gives for example, 163, that I could get 164 by replacing one of the '0' with a '1'. However the results I get are far from that. By replacing a single character by a single value I get a totally different hash result. For this example the 163 could become 84, which puzzles me.

My function for calculating the hash is quite simple but here it is anyway.

```
int calcHash(const char *filename) {
    int hash = 0;
    int c;
    FILE *fh = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (!fh)
        return -1;

    while((c = fgetc(fh)) != EOF)
        hash = (hash + c) % 256;

    fclose(fh);

    return hash;
}
```

And I call it from main() with this statement.

```
int hash = calcHash(argv[0]);
```

What exactly happens during compilation? Anyway I can get more predictable hash values?

Perhaps this doesn't happen with all compilers. I am just totally baffled with that unexpected behaviour.

I'm using gcc on Ubuntu.

Comment: *In an attempt to temper proof my executable* Don't do that. You are just making life harder for people with a legitimate need to hexedit your executable, and not hindering piracy or reverse engineering even a little.

Comment: Why would people have a legitimate need to hexedit my executable? I mean, really?

Comment: If you run your algorithm multiple times on the same file does it produce the same hash each time? That should be all a hash function needs to do. In fact, the behavior you described is what you _want_ the hash to do. It will make it easy to check if your exe has been hexedited. Also I believe the word is _tamper_ proof

Comment: When I run it multiple times I always get the same hash result. I want to include that value within my executable so it can check itself. However, with the explained behaviour it becomes next to impossible to do so. Thanks for correcting me on the spelling of "tamper".

Comment: How are you compiling it, exactly? All executables contains housekeeping information, some with debugging information, perhaps some versions might even even include timestamps.

Recommend compiling the program twice, and compare the hex dumps of the resulting `a.out` to see what's changed even if you change no program text.

Comment: My program uses Gtk3 and libharu splited over 10 source files and I use eclipse as IDE so the compile process is somewhat more complex than just a basic 'gcc myprog.c -o myprog'. However I did clean and recompile my project several times (6 totals) without changing anything in the code and I always get the same hash value in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a harder problem than it looks, as well as being a worse idea than it looks - I can't un-recommend this enough.

I worked on a customer system where they did this, and it was as much of a pain in the ass as has been suggested, so I ended up reverse engineering it to write my own re-seal utility so I could edit the damn file and apply the new hash. And these changes were **always** to the benefit of the software vendor and its customers, never to steal it or anything.

But in any case, as best as I can remember it worked by including some data areas in the code:

```
char tamper_marker_1[] = "SOME MAGIC STRING";
int  fileSize;
unsigned checksum;
char endmarker[] = "OTHER MAGIC STRING";
```

The external apply-seal program would open the `.exe` and find the magic  string, which lead to the above data area, and would stuff in the `fileSize` and the `checksum` of all data *other than* in the seal-info area.

The executable would test for tampering by opening itself as a file, and performing the same checks.

Under Windows, you can use `GetModuleFilename()` to find the full path of the executable, and on Linux you can open `/proc/12345/exe` (where 12345 is your process ID) which is a symbolic link to the program and so the same thing.

I don't know if I'm contributing to making the world a worse place by describing this, but SO is for questions and answers, and perhaps there's a legitimate need. Please don't do it unless you really, really have to.

EDIT: You might point out that very few will go to the trouble I did of reverse engineering, but I'll point out that all you need is *one person* to create the re-seal tool and release it, and all your clever work is for naught.

EDIT2: As I think about this, if it's just one program, you wouldn't have to actually reverse engineer the algorithm - you'd just have to be able to disassemble it to nop-out the test.

Comment: Looks like your solution is what I'll go with, If I do indeed decide to tamper proof my program. I am totally aware that there is always a way to reverse engineer and disassemble code. I just wish to make it harder to do so.